# Facebook profile to fan page and likes from webpage

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, fan-page

**Starting point:**

1. I have a webpage with, say, 100 likes.
2. I also have a Facebook profile with, say, 300 friends.
3. It started as two different things, but turned out to be the same.
   However, the 100 likes are not from people amongst the friends in
   the Facebook profile.

**Problem:**
What I would like to do, obviously, is have the better of both worlds.
How can I convert my profile into a fan page (yes, I know [how to do this](http://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902/)) but also keep all my friends as likes, plus the likes of my webpage (of course it sounds too good!).

In other words, is it possible to link my webpage to the new fan page in a way that the likes of the webpage don't get lost, and everyone that likes my fan page, also likes my webpage (and vice versa)?

If not, what would you recommend me to do? Just reset the likes on the page and start over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I really don't think this is possible. I'm sure you can imagine why - if it was possible, then it would not really be safe to like anything on Facebook, because someone could then merge it with a totally unrelated webpage or fan page without reaffirming the "like" with existing users/likers.

Comment: hmm.. somehow it makes sense :)
But can't you change everything about a group too? Name, description, photos and everyone remains there..

Comment: My guess is they wouldn't want to make it any easier to do something misleading. Facebook would need to create a tool to merge the Open Graph Objects associated with your page and your website. It is possible they will do that some day - they clearly have created some specialized migration tools as you have linked to. There is also this migration process which is similar to what you are looking for, but I don't think it is exactly what you need (unless you were using the "Like Button Social Plugin" specifically): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/